# Django Admin: Categorizing Indexes

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm learning django and I am trying to categorize the admin indexes(if that's what it is called).

I want my models to be categorized like `myinfo` under `information` and `region`, `city`, and `zip` under `address`

If I register my models in the admin it will display as

[image]

How do I do it like this?

[image]

Comment: And how are they displayed now?

Comment: I just register them with `admin.site.register()`, I'm trying to find a proper tutorial in displaying the indexes but no luck

Comment: Look, you show us a picture of how you want your admin to look like. It looks like a pretty regular admin with a handful of custom modules in the sidebar. But we have no idea how does your admin interface look like now. So we just can't help you until you clarify where are you now and what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give custom `verbose_name`s to the apps' [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/). And [specify those](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#for-application-users) `AppConfig`s in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` instead of actual apps' names.

By default Django groups the models by their respective applications. If you want to change this behavior and group them not on a app basis, make a [custom `AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-adminsite) and override its [`get_apps_list()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L476) method. You'll also need to modify the `admin/index.html` template.